# Create Dropdown Attribute for Products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-attribute

I want to create Dropdown Attribute for Products and want to fetch data from the database in created Dropdown Attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute( Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY ,'attribute_code');
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        print_r ($options);

<select name="some name">
<?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"><?php echo $option['label'] ?></option>
 <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

My updated answer to you

load your table collection by
`$coll = Mage::getModel('yourModel')->getCollection();`

And foreach loop in your collection add all your option in $option as lable and value pair for each option

```
$attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
$attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code');
$attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
 $attribute->setData('option',$option);
        $attribute->save();
```

Try above code and let me know if it is not working

Comment: i want to data in the dropdown from the database.

Comment: It will give you all option and you can add options using foreach loop

Comment: it gives output like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => [value] => ) )

Comment: It has attribute  data or not?

Comment: in my attribute there is no data

Comment: please check updated answer and fill some data in your dropdown attribute and then try and let me know

Comment: but i dont want to fill any data in dropdown attribute , i want to add data form the other table which is i created like "upload_image_upload".

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in

Comment: getting error like above using updated answer

Comment: What you exactly code please update in your que

Comment: $coll = Mage::getModel('upload_image')->getCollection();
$attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
$attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'image101');
$attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
 $attribute->setData('option',$option);
        $attribute->save();
 ?>

Comment: I think there should me mistake in  'upload_image' plase add your config.xml for that

Comment: <models>
            <upload_image>
                <class>Upload_Image_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>upload_image_resource</resourceModel>
            </upload_image>
            <upload_image_resource>
                <class>Upload_Image_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <upload>
                        <table>upload_image_upload</table>

Comment: your model should be Mage::getModel('upload_image/upload')->getCollection()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44826/discussion-between-harshil-and-murtuza).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a source model (like like Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product) as well as an attribute that uses the source model.

In the source model you need to query the table and return the results in the getAllOptions function.

You can look here for a guide:

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/